# Xunit and msbuild issue

Tags: msbuild, xunit

I have the visual studio AND the msbuild xunit runners nuget packages installed.

I can build the project locally with no issue AND run xunit with no problem.

I can open the solution in visual studio on the build server from the source code that was brought down during the build AND run xunit with no problem.

From a visual studio command line I can build and run the solution using msbuild.exe AND it runs the xunit tests with no problem.

When the build itself runs it fails with:

"This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\packages\xunit.core.2.4.1\build\xunit.core.props."

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exact same thing happening to me after I moved the project to another folder and re-imported it. I could see a warning icon on assemblies under References and they all had empty paths.
Neither *nuget restore MySolution.sln* or *msbuild -t:restore* helped, so I just uninstalled all of the nuget-packages in the test-project, removed references manually and installed them again. However, still no help.
The solution was to remove packages as mentioned above, including removing references, and then clean up wrong assembly paths in the csproj-file (still had wrong path to the cached packages). Then install need packages again.